# Why does the QGIS 'project properties' option disappear in Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, gui

For some reason my 'project properties' button has disappeared for good. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and QGIS 1.8.

Sometimes it would straight up disappear, to return later, but now its just 'gone'.

I'll try to re-install, but has anyone else noticed this?

I have uninstalled the QT framework (to combat some bugs in QGIS and Scribus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug was reported here: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4434 and is already fixed in QGIS Master.

The installation of QGIS Master under Ubuntu is described here: http://qgismalaysia.blogspot.de/2012/04/ubuntu-1204-qgis-1990-installation.html