# QGIS 2.14 Ubuntu 16.04 "Project properties" menu missing

Tags: qgis

Could you help me to understand why my QGIS configuration doesn't show me the **Project properties** sub menu found in **Project** menu ?

QGIS version : 2.14

Ubuntu distrib : 16.04

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: possible bug but this was a solution in a previous version http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43734/why-does-the-qgis-project-properties-option-disappear-in-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The patch relate 1.8 QGIS version ... probably outdated for the 2.14 version. Until then I've downgraded QGIS to 2.8 version.